# Is it possible to handle long int or big integers in (g)awk script?

Tags: awk, precision, long-integer

Due to awk handling all numerics with double precision, long integers (as the type long int, or more commonly: long), will reach a roof at 53 bits (or 16.5 ish digits). This means that if the program gets handed a long int from an x86_64 architecture, where long int is 64-bits we will be in trouble. Is there anyway for an awk script to handle this case?

It is not really an option to use  -M or -bignum during startup, as the script is a bit too big for an awk script and I do not want to change the general behavior. Print using,

```
printf("%d\n",1234567890123456789)
```

is not really an option. Even though all the digits will be printed, the precision is still only precise until the the last "7" (12345678901234567**68**).

Anyone having a suggestion, which does not involve to do inline python or perl?

BR
Patrik

**PS**

I have ofc seen questions to handle "very large integers", or "long integers", where "long" means very large. Further, these questions are rather refering to inline awk in bash, where -M is not a problem. However, this question specifically refers to handling the type long int in script mode.

**EDIT**

Just to clarify more. The question which marked as a duplicate does not answer my question, as I mentioned that I wanted to solve this in a script, without altering the behavior of awk. Adding the -M flag will change the behavior of all the other 100,000 lines of awk and I do not want to do this.

In other words I want 99,999 lines of awk to behave as if the flag -M was not set and 1 line to handle long integer. I am well aware of this might not be possible in awk, but I figured I would try here before I give up.

Comment: I don't think that it's possible :/

Comment: @oguzismail I think so too, but I figured I would try here before I give up. The option is to use inline perl or python, but it would be much better to have direct awk support.

Comment: Do you really mean your `awk` script is 100,000 lines long?  Or, are you referring to the input file to be processed by `awk`?

Comment: @karakfa yes, the awk script is that long. Or actually longer, but this is not really the point. It is enough to mention it is long.

Comment: Good luck.  If you don't see why a 100K lines long awk script might be a problem (can it still be called *a script* at this point?) I can't convince you otherwise.

Comment: @karakfa Well, it can of course be considered a script, though a long one. It is of course not a 100k lines code block. It is split into different functions and multiple files. It is all awk though. The function starting everything is a few hundred lines, but this is mostly parameter settings (and have been working and untouched for years). But this is not the point with the question. I can of course see the gain in rewriting this in another language than awk, but I can also see the point in keeping things that work and have a fairly low technical debt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you mention the `--bignum` option, I'm assuming you are using gawk.

I don't think gawk offers a way to use the MP library for one specific program line among thousands. But, as a workaround, you could use the arbitrary precision calculator `bc` as a co-process.

In other words, instead of:

```
gawk -v var=123456789012345676890 '
    BEGIN {
        var2 = var + 1
        print var " + 1 = " var2
    }
'
```

... which erroneously displays:

```
123456789012345676890 + 1 = 123456789012345683968
```

You could use:

```
gawk -v var=123456789012345676890 '
    BEGIN {
        print var " + 1" |& "bc"
        "bc" |& getline var2
        print var " + 1 = " var2
    }
'
```

... which would correctly display:

```
123456789012345676890 + 1 = 123456789012345676891
```